# Access in a function to the scope of the clicked object in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have to access a function to the scope of the clicked object in angular. I have to write to the console the id of the object, but without passing the object to the called function by the click event. 
Could some one help me with my problem?
Below is the code what I have achieved so far.

```
<ul data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
 <li data-ng-repeat="x in names" data-ng-bind="x.title" data-ng-click="fnct(x)"></li>
</ul>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
 $scope.names = [{id: 2345, title: 'title1'}, {id: 9876, title: 'title2'}];
 $scope.fnct = function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.id);
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` keyword which will refer to current child scope so you don't have to pass `x` into function explicitly:

```
<ul data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in names" data-ng-bind="x.title" data-ng-click="fnct()"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is complete example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{id: 2345, title: 'title1'}, {id: 9876, title: 'title2'}];
    $scope.fnct = function() {
        console.log(this.x.id);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in names" data-ng-bind="x.title" data-ng-click="fnct()"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did not think was accessible by "this".
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ul data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
 <li data-ng-repeat="x in names" data-ng-bind="x.title" data-ng click="fnct(x.id)"></li>
</ul>
<script>
 angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{id: 2345, title: 'title1'}, {id: 9876, title: 'title2'}];
  $scope.fnct = function(id) {
   console.log(id);
  }
 });
</script>
```